# Exit module code midway through import, but treat import as successful

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a module (which I wrote and can freely edit) that I am importing, and I want to be able to stop its execution part-way through while treating its import as successful. Unfortunately, if I, say, raise an exception during the import, then the module is not successfully imported and is not available. Is it possible to abort execution (without e.g., wrapping subsequent code in an `if ...:` block) simply by calling something similar to `sys.exit()`? `sys.exit()` does not work because it raises `SystemExit`, which makes the import fail.

Comment: Mostly curious, why not just wrap the rest of the code in an `if` statement?

Comment: Alternatively, write two separate modules and import one or the other

Comment: You _could_ do this, but… Write an import hook. Your hook can insert a `stop_import` callback into builtins that the module being imported can call. Or it can execute the module code statement by statement (ala runpy mode) and build a module manually out of the resulting namespace, which means it can handle a special exceptions (or any exception, if you prefer) as "exit early". If that sounds impossible rather than a fun experiment, you probably don't want to do it.

Comment: @ChootsMagoots The reason I want to do this is because it's very quick to move a single "exit" line vertically to include or exclude code. Once I add an `if`, I have to deal with correct indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other languages, a `return` is not allowed at module level (i.e. outside a function).

As you found out, raising an exception is not a good solution.

Alternative solutions include:

- wrap the remaining code in an `if`.
- wrap the main code in a function, and use `return` to interrupt it at some point.
- wrap the main code in a `for`:

```
for _ in [0]:
    always_executed()

    if some_condition: break

    sometimes_executed()

    break
```

not the best readability (due to the `for` which is somewhat misleading).

I would prefer a `main()` function or an `if:`.